# TelerikRadGrid how to insert,update and delete into SQL database

Tags: c#, telerik

I am using Telerik controls in Visual Studio 2008, in RadGrid. I create a PopUp windows includes all the TextBoxes and controls that I need to use in database but how can I declare a function in order to insert, update and delete ? And where!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Data Access Layer](http://www.reflectionit.nl/dal.aspx) for Definition of the the function to send the request to database

If you want to use SQL Server. Following is the code.

```
using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("YourConnection string")) { 
    con.Open(); 
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(); 
    string expression = "Parameter value"; 
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; 
    cmd.CommandText = "Your Stored Procedure"; 
    cmd.Parameters.Add("Your Parameter Name", 
                SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = expression;    
    cmd.Connection = con; 
    using (IDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) 
    { 
        if (dr.Read()) 
        { 
        } 
    } 
}
```

You can also use [Microsoft Enterprise Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff632023.aspx)

You can Use [Business Logic Layer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581779.aspx) to call the database layer function and also can perform validations before sending the data to `Presentation Layer`

Finally, You can call the [Business Logic Layer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581779.aspx) objects in your `Presentation layer`