# Connecting ASP.NET web site in Visual Studio 2010 to SQL Server 2008

Tags: asp.net, database, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

i am new to .net environment and do not know how to connect a database. can anybody help me with it,and if possible give sample code for basic operations like insert a value into a DB,read a record etc

Answer (score 0):

MSDN is the way to go:

[How to: Connect to Data in a Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxk9yw1t%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

[Check out this marked answer in SO. You can use Presentation/BLL/DAL/Object Library for variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6149472/telerikradgrid-how-to-insert-update-and-delete-into-sql-database/6149539#6149539)